# Buff.163 get sales history Python

Tags: python, json, steam

I got a small problem with a API request to Buff.163.
I want to get the 10 last sales from some items in my database.

[image]

I already found the API request:

```
https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/bill_order?game=csgo&goods_id=33882
```

The answer from the API is:

!{'code': 'Login Required', 'error': '请先登录', 'extra': None}

So I need to be logged in to get this information,
but I don't know how to do that. I have tried to generate the QR-Code, with which you can login via the mobile app, but without success.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in order to use BUFF API you need to have an account. To register a BUFF account you will need a working mobile number, without the number it is not possible. The app and QR code are optional. Enter the number press "Get code" and input the received SMS. After that the API works just fine.
P.S. I have heard there are some problems in USA/Canada with that, but in Europe it works fine